# SignalR not pushing the message back to client

Tags: angularjs, signalr

I am trying to connect to message queue and push back all the notifications to the web(Angularjs) using SignalR.So everytime there is a message is the queue the listener should process the message and refresh the web page.
The listener(SignalR.SelfHost.DotNetClient) is working correctly pushing the notification to Send method in SignalR.SelfHost.Server.However the message doesn't get pushed back the client in the web.The broadcastMessage method in the client is not invoked.Please let me know what is wrong here.
Even the alert within hub.start is not firing.
I have 3 projects here
SignalR.SelfHost.DotNetClient - listener to message queue

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8080/");
        var serverHub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("NotificationHub");
        //serverHub.On("broadcastMessage", message => System.Console.WriteLine(message));
        hubConnection.Start().Wait();

            // Send a json array message to the server
       var message="{'externalDeviceId': '0102030405060700A100010A', 'deviceId':'28C2A18F647B2F81','friendlyName' : 'unknown','userId' : 'HHFR','deviceFullType' : 'iOS-iPad' ,'drmDeviceId':'28C2A18F647B2F81', 'accountId' : 'HH0A','drmDeviceType': 'IOS', 'preferences ':    {        'audioLanguage':'FIN',        'friendlyName':'unknown',        'audioDescriptionFlag':false,        'bannerDisplayTimeout':7,        'isConnected':true,        'presenceStatus':'ONLINE'    } }".Replace("'", "\"");
        serverHub.Invoke("Send", "[" + message + "]").Wait();
```

}

SignalR.SelfHost.Server -Self hosted SignalR

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{        
    public static IHubContext HubContext
    {
        get
        {
            if (_context == null)
                _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();

            return _context;
        }
    }
    static IHubContext _context = null;
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        //Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);
        HubContext.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message);
    }       
}
```

Web - AngularJS

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs/" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        /*Set the hubs URL for the connection */
        debugger;
        $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:8080/signalr";
        /* Declare a proxy to reference the hub.*/
        var hubClient = $.connection.notificationHub;
        //$.connection.hub.start();
        /* Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.*/
        hubClient.client.broadcastMessage = function (data) {
            alert(data);
         }
        /* Start the connection.*/
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            /*  Call the Send method on the hub */
            alert('Hi');

        });
```

Comment: Try adding [`$.connection.hub.logging = true;`](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#logging) before your call to $.connection.hub.start so you can see diagnostic info logged to the developer console by SignalR using `console.log`. I would also suggesting an error callback to your call to `hub.start()` so you can look at the actual error `.fail(function (error) { /* ... */ })` that is preventing the connection from being established.

Comment: The fact that you specify absolute addresses in the JS client code, makes me think it does not live under the same domain/application of the server. If that's the case, you might be missing Cross-Domain support. Isn't it?

Comment: Thank you guys.Both responses helped.I put hub.start().fail(function (error) { /* ... */ }).The error said that client and server were different versions so upgraded the server to the latest version.Also put the following in the startup to enable cross site public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HubConfiguration();
            config.EnableJSONP = true;
            app.MapSignalR(config);
        }